# Importing service using Ionic-Angular causes Karma test suite to fail

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine, karma-webpack

I am having trouble with my [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/latest/index.html) tests. I am trying to import a service which makes use of an object within the [Ionic-Angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-angular) package.

Whenever I try to run `npm test` to start up the test suite, it compiles fine, however after that I am being displayed with  a large error message.

I haven't been able to find much anywhere else, and was wondering if I could get a little help.

What I have found is that the `./components/app/app-root` import is called in an npm module 'ionic-angular'.

[Screenshot of the error I am shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhEE9.png)

Comment: I think this `app-root` import path is wrong in the spec file where you have created `TestBed`. You need to provide more code to get an exact answer otherwise this question will be closed soon.